# Include multiple subdirectories for external makefile in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I am tyring to debug a C++ project in CDT eclipse.The project structure that I have is:

```
*Parent directory|
                |
                ----- SubDir 1
                |        |   
                |        |
                |        |
                |        |
                |       --- *.h and *.cpp  (header files and c++ source code)
                |       
                |
                |
                ----- SubDir 2
                        |
                        |
                        |
                        --- *.h and *.cpp  (header files and c+= source code)*
```

Currently I have a shell script which compiles everything and generates an executable.The shell script has following command.And it works fine through the command line.

```
g++ -I SubDir1 -I SubDir2 Main.cpp SubDir1/*.cpp SubDir2/*.cpp -o exec
```

But `-I` somehow does not work with eclipse.Is there a way I can achieve this eclipse.How can I include multiple sub-directories in an external or target makefile.

Comment: Which template did you used while created C/C++ project in eclipse. Is it executable,makefile or autotools project? Show your makefile content. What error are you getting?

Comment: I could be wrong but I thought space between -I and the directory was not allowed.